# Getting UserWarning: Test/Validation dataset column 'browser_name' has levels not trained on: [Android, Midori, Opera Mini, Other] for H2O GBM model

Tags: machine-learning, h2o

I trained a H2O GBM model (H2O version 3.22.0.1) using many categorical columns but when i try to predict on test data it is giving me warnings for unknown categorical levels in test. Does H2O GBM not handle then unseen categorical levels automatically? or is there a specific version where this capability is added?

Kindly suggest any tips to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `fold_assignment="Stratified"`. See [fold_assignment](https://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/algo-params/fold_assignment.html) documentation for more details.